# Sorting arrays and comparing array values php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, chart.js

Good day guys, I'm working on plotting data on charts using ChartJs and Laravel, I need to plot data based on months and I want the whole 12 months showing on the chart even without data,

I have months in an array ['January', 'February'....

Then I have my data here:

```
     $stats = DB::table('wallet_payouts')
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->get([
            DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M") as date'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as value')
        ]);

    $labels = [];
    $data = [];
    foreach ($months as $month){
        foreach ($stats as $stat){
            if ($month == $stat->date){
                array_push($labels, $stat->date);
                array_push($data, $stat->value);
            }else{
                array_push($labels, $month);
                array_push($data, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

But the issue is instead of 12 months after the loop I'm getting 24... Duplicates and the data also in 24... I want the months to just match with the data without the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
$stats = DB::table('wallet_payouts')
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->get([
            DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M") as date'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as value')
        ]);

$labels = $months;
$data = [];
$temp = [];
foreach ($stats as $stat){
    $temp[$stat->date] = $stat->value;
}
foreach($months as $month){
    if(array_key_exists($month,$temp)){
        array_push($data, $temp[$month]);
    } else {
        array_push($data, 0);
    }
}
```